# How to save the value of the number of touches in a button Android Studio

Tags: java, android, save, sharedpreferences

I want to save the number value so that when close the app it continues to be saved and when open it the progress is maintained. I don't know why SharedPreferences don't work.
I have tried in many ways but either the app forces it to close or it just doesn't work

number = numero

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView contador;
   
    int numero = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("valor", numero);
        int data = mPrefs.getInt("valor", numero);

        contador = findViewById(R.id.contador);
        
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        numero++;
        contador.setText(String.valueOf(numero));

     
        SharedPreferences.Editor data = data.edit();
        data.putInt("tag", numero).commit();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same sharedPreferences for retrieving the values.
also, get the values by the same key you saved them. below is an example you can follow.

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("valor", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
try{
    int data = mPrefs.getInt("tag", numero);
}
catch(NullPointerException e){
    e.printStackTrace()
}
public void onClick(View v) {

      numero++;
      contador.setText(String.valueOf(numero));

 
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
      editor.putInt("tag", numero).commit();
   }
};
```

Comment: still not working, the value is not saved when reopening the app, but thank you

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.greenvegg.elhuevo, PID: 21060
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.greenvegg.elhuevo/com.greenvegg.elhuevo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:164)